# Why am I getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval(function() {

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/alaris/admin/product_notification",
          data: JSON.stringify({ product:"product"}),
          success: function(res) {
            $("#product_notify").html(res);
            //alert(res);
          }   
        });
     }, 5000);
    </script>
```

When I'm running the above code it displays following error message in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Function.n.parseJSON (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
    at Object.success (custom.js:85)
    at j (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
    at x (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
n.parseJSON @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4
success @ custom.js:85
j @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2
fireWith @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:2
x @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:4
```

Can anyone would find what the error is?

Comment: What is the response coming back from the request? Is it valid JSON?

Comment: Yep ! the program is working as it is. But the problem is it shows the above error in browser console.

Comment: Right, but what is the responseText from the request? You need to check that in the network tab of the console after the request has been made

Answer (score 0):

If `product` is an object:

```
JSON.stringify({ "product" : product })
```